# Extension of "Viewing connection details" for visualization of variable values

Tags: openmdao

"Viewing Connection Details" is a great functionnality in order to visualize all the variable bounds, connections and units.

Can it be easily extended to store and visualize the converged values of design variables (at least scalar ones)? How? It could be valuable to interact with design teams not familiar with python.

Comment: are you talking about the view_model functionality documented here: http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/usr-guide/tutorials/visualizing-model-connections.html?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the view_connections functionality of openmdao : -> http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/usr-guide/tutorials/detailed-connection-viewer.html  Would it be possible to add a column to store the numerical results ?

Comment: I'll add a story to our tracker to replace the 'size' column with the actual value.  Initially it'll probably support just scalar values, but eventually we could pop up some sort of array viewer when the user clicks in the value cell if the value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I just merged an update to the detailed connection viewer to the master branch.  The center 'Size' column has been replaced with the value of the variable (in target units unless the source is unconnected).  If the string representation of the value is too big to fit in a cell, a 'View' button is displayed in the cell that you can click on to see a scrollable viewer for the value.  The viewer is very crude, but at least you'll be able to see array values. I also added the ability to set the initial source and target filter strings from the command line.